# Get query string parameter value wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get orderID parameter value from the URL in WordPress but unable. I

used `$_GET['orderID']` like do in PHP but its nots working for me.

```
  http://www.example.com/thankyou/?orderID=z1r9HJHH
```

Thanks

Comment: it should work, are trying to get it in template or any other file?

Comment: @Sightman are you using woocommerce?

Comment: I'm calling  ajax file in template and using this code in ajax file.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez no I'm working on PayFort payment integration.

Comment: @Sightman add some of your actual code. I might be able to help if i see some of it.

Comment: function myfunction(){
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: {},
    url:"update.php",
    success:function(result){
 }
  });
};

Comment: @jameshwartlopez Above function im using on my template and sending request using jquery ajax at update.php. I need to get orderID at update.php page.

Comment: You're using `type: "POST"` in your Ajax, so shouldn't you be using `$_POST['orderId']` to access the variable? Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information (don't put your code in comments that people might miss).

Answer (score 0):

try get_query_var function in WP. will find more details on below link.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: I tried this also like this get_query_var('orderID'); but same result.